# Where is the best place to perform authentication in a microservice architecture?

Tags: security, authentication, authorization, microservices

I see different opinions among software engineers regarding where to place authentication in a Microservice architecture.
Many support the idea that authentication should be placed at the API gateway level and only the Authorization at Microservice level.

For authentication I mean checking a JWT that was issued after authentication with credentials, for example...

Now, if the API gateway is the only entry point of our backend then it is reasonable to have it in the Frontline when it comes to authenticate the requests.
The problem is that the API gateway, being a proxy, shouldn't really be bound to the underlying services, right?

Let's say that some of  the endpoints require authentication and some of them are publicly accessible. I feel that in this case it's better to have it at  the Microservice, since the Microservice knows all the details of the API that it exposes.

Otherwise the API gateway should ask the Microservice if the endpoint is public or not or get this information from a database.
But wouldn't be too much of overhead to perform this request to the service/database everytime the gateway is hit?

Furthermore, depending on the framework we use to implement the security layer we might not have the chance to check the accessibility of an endpoint at runtime. So, whenever we make an endpoint public we should redeploy the gateway to get the new information about what requires authentication and what not.

What are your suggestions regarding this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it strictly from a security perspective.
From what I have seen with microservice architectures, the gateway only performs authentication, each micro service / endpoint needs to handle its own authorization checks at a bare minimum.

So for your public URLs, the gateway would not perform any authentication checks.
For your private/secured endpoints, the gateway will perform authentication checks and authorization checks at a microservice level, but you will still need to handle the business rules to be followed.

Example:

- `/public/article1` - does not need any authentication or authorization checks
- `/private/newsletter` - requires authentication from gateway, but may not require authorization checks from the microservice
- `/private/account` - should require both authentication + authorization check from gateway as well as from the microservice to make sure you are accessing only your account.